# How to transition routes in vuepress?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuepress

Reading the [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition) documentation, the way to achieve route transitions is by doing:

```
<transition>
  <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

But the problem is that VuePress is handling all the routing behind the scenes, so I can't figure out where to put that transition component.

Is there anyway to do this in VuePress?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own theme or [eject default](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/default-theme-config/#custom-page-class).

In your Page.vue component wrap `<Content />` component in `<transition>`

```
<transition name="fade">
  <Content :custom="false"/>
</transition>
```

If you want to change something except `<Content />` part, use binding

```
<transition name="header-fade" mode="out-in">
  <header v-bind:key="$page.key">
    <h1>{{ $page.title }}</h1>
  </header>
</transition>
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know –
Router transitions won't be possible, because as soon as you run 'vuepress build' the whole site will be static.
So no more routing is done and therefore the page will reload new content instead of dynamically adding it.

Comment: As far as I understand it content is dynamically loaded and the static site is just a fallback.